# Ошибка discord: AttributeError("'int' object has no attribute 'id'")

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Кoд:

```
import discord
from discord import utils
 
import config
 
class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged on as {0}!'.format(self.user))
 
    async def on_raw_reaction_add(self, payload):
        if payload.message_id == config.POST_ID:
            channel = self.get_channel(payload.channel_id) # получаем объект канала
            message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id) # получаем объект сообщения
            member = utils.get(message.guild.members, id=payload.user_id) # получаем объект пользователя который поставил реакцию

            try:
                emoji = str(payload.emoji) # эмоджик который выбрал юзер
                role = config.ROLES[emoji] # объект выбранной роли (если есть)
                await member.add_roles(781449031338950666)

            except KeyError as e:
                print('[ERROR] KeyError, no role found for ' + emoji)
            except Exception as e:
                print(repr(e))
 
    async def on_raw_reaction_remove(self, payload):
        channel = self.get_channel(payload.channel_id) # получаем объект канала
        message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id) # получаем объект сообщения
        member = utils.get(message.guild.members, id=payload.user_id) # получаем объект пользователя который поставил реакцию
 
        try:
            emoji = str(payload.emoji) # эмоджик который выбрал юзер
            role = utils.get(message.guild.roles, id=config.ROLES[emoji]) # объект выбранной роли (если есть)
 
            await member.remove_roles(role)
            print('[SUCCESS] Role {1.name} has been remove for user {0.display_name}'.format(member, role))
 
        except KeyError as e:
            print('[ERROR] KeyError, no role found for ' + emoji)
        except Exception as e:
            print(repr(e))
 
# RUN
client = MyClient()
client.run(config.TOKEN)
```

Суть в том что после токго как юзер ставит реакцию ему должна присуждаться роль, но появляется постоянно следующая ошибка `(AttributeError("'int' object has no attribute 'id'"))`. До этого была другая ошибка `(AttributeError("'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add_roles'"))`, от нее удалось избавиться за счет того что юзер должен находится в одном из голосовых каналов во время прожатия реакции.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос полный стек с ошибкой (кнопка [edit]). А так, у вас в коде где-то у объекта-целого числа вызывается поле `id`. Хотя... я не нашел в коде `.id`, а значит вы куда-то неправильное значение передаете, где ожидался объект, а вы передали туда целое число. А где это произошло можно увидеть в трассе стека

Comment: В трейсбеке внизу поизучайте на какой строке Exception.(В VS code ide нажимаешь на ссылку трейсбека попадаешь на строку-думаешь:))